# Keep language preference after page refresh from LocalStorage in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, local-storage

How to keep the English language after refreshing the page? The default language is NL, when I switch English and after the refresh, the language is again NL.
Here is my code.

```
const languages = [
    {
        id: 'nl',
        title: 'Dutch',
        flag: 'nl'
    },
    {
        id: 'en',
        title: 'English',
        flag: 'us'
    }
];

function LanguageSwitcher(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const currentLanguageId = useSelector(({ i18n }) => i18n.language);
    const currentLanguage = languages.find(lng => lng.id === currentLanguageId);

    const [menu, setMenu] = useState(null);


    
    const langMenuClick = event => {
        setMenu(event.currentTarget);

    };

    const langMenuClose = () => {
        setMenu(null);
    };

    
    
    function handleLanguageChange(lng) {
        dispatch(changeLanguage(lng.id));
        
        langMenuClose();
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Button className="h-40 w-64" onClick={langMenuClick}>
                <img
                    className="mx-4 min-w-20"
                    src={`assets/images/flags/${currentLanguage.flag}.png`}
                    alt={currentLanguage.title}
                />

                <Typography className="mx-4 font-semibold uppercase" color="textSecondary">
                    {currentLanguage.id}
                </Typography>
            </Button>

            <Popover
                open={Boolean(menu)}
                anchorEl={menu}
                onClose={langMenuClose}
                anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'bottom',
                    horizontal: 'center'
                }}
                transformOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'top',
                    horizontal: 'center'
                }}
                classes={{
                    paper: 'py-8'
                }}
            >
                {languages.map(lng => (
                    <MenuItem key={lng.id} onClick={() => handleLanguageChange(lng)}>
                        <ListItemIcon className="min-w-40">
                            <img className="min-w-20" src={`assets/images/flags/${lng.flag}.png`} alt={lng.title} />
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={lng.title} />
                    </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Popover>
        </>
    );
}

export default LanguageSwitcher;
```

Comment: In the above code, you are not setting the value in local storage.

Comment: Can you post the code where you initialize your Redux store?

Comment: how to set the value?

Comment: export const changeLanguage = languageId => (dispatch, getState) => {
    Change Language

 return i18n.changeLanguage(languageId).then(() => {
  dispatch(i18nSlice.actions.languageChanged(languageId));
 });
};

const i18nSlice = createSlice({
 name: 'i18n',
 initialState: {
  language: i18n.options.lng
 },
 reducers: {
  languageChanged: (state, action) => {
   state.language = action.payload;
  }
 }
});

export default i18nSlice.reducer;